# Cache lookup failed for function 1 while activating PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, debian

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.5 on a remote server (Debian). I created a database inside then I attempted to enable PostGIS but it wasn't successful.

I had this error : `cache lookup failed for function 1`

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers that such a search yields, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125036/postgres-cache-lookup-failed-for-constraint-34055).

Comment: I don't see how it could solve my issue!

Comment: Well, it suggests that your error might be caused by database corruption. I have created lots of clean instances of Postgres/Postgis on Debian, Centos and Ubuntu servers and never seen this error, so, it is a decent guess. If the error were Postgis related, you would normally get errors about specifically named functions, not just function 1. Have you tried creating a non-spatial table, just to see if Postgres is working properly.

Comment: Yes I did try this, I created non geometric tables and it works as expected. The problem occurs while enabling postgis either via pgadmin or shell. This occurs not only for postgis but also for other extensions as well.

Comment: I remember that prior to the 10.5 version a previous person was working with the 9.x version and he changed it to the actual one. May this switch cause such a bizarre behaviour or do you envision something else? I tried to update postgis yet when I did it I was told that I'm working with the updated one.

Comment: I assume you used pg_upgrade or pg_dump, pg_restore to upgrade the DB. There are Postgis scripts that will convert from one version to another, you can't just run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`. So, without knowing how you did the upgrades, it is hard to tell, but, yes, it could be the source of the behavior you are seeing. You should edit the question outlining what you did to update both Postgres and Postgis. It is highly relevant information.